# Kafka Cluster: Setup consumer on a new VM

Tags: python, apache-kafka, virtual-machine, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka cluster(3.X) running on a VM and Producer is writing messages to the cluster successfully.
I want to run a consumer on a new VM using Python code. Do I have to install Kafka cluster again and then write Python code to consume data?

I tried CLI consumer on the Kafka cluster VM and it works fine but I want to setup consumer on a new machine as it will represent a real-world use-case. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're running a single instance... A "cluster" (more than one server) would be recommended for Kafka, but it's not necessary.

The Kafka server defaults to only accept local connections from the same host, but if you configure correctly it'll accept remote connections perfectly fine, from any client language.